# Javafx TriangleMesh collision detection

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision, mesh, javafx-8

I would like to know if there is an easy way to detect when one TriangleMesh collides with another one or maybe a TriangleMesh collides with a Point3D

I tested using a Point3D.  I placed it at 0, 0 and gave it a width and height of 1.  The tested TriangleMesh is an object that doesn't have anything at 0, 0, but the intersect method still returned true.  I am guessing it detects collision on the bounding box and not the surface of the Mesh

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you want to be looking at the PickResult class.. I haven't gotten that far myself yet, but I am pretty sure it is what you're looking for.. good luck! post results!

Comment: I took the C# code from http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:40778.  I don't understand what I did, but I did it :)  There is alot of code, too much to post here.

Comment: Submitted too quickly.I believe the PickResult is just for when you click on the mesh with your mouse.  I wanted to slice a 3D object.  I still need to use PickResult so that I can build manual supports into my system.  Maybe next week